# Change known words 1 and 3 of a string whilst keeping unknown word 2 constant

Tags: sed, wildcards, string

I have a text file and I'm trying to find all instances of `Word1 Word2 Word3` in a text file and replace it with `Word4 Word2 Word5`. Word2 is unknown string but the rest of the words are known.

Here is what I have tried so far

I have a string `(...) foobarfoo (...)` and I want to replace it with `(...) hatbarcar (...)`

```
sed -i 's/foo.*foo/hat.*car/g' data.txt
```

but the result I get is

```
(...) hat.*car (...)
```

So the wildcard is finding the word string I want but I then want to use this same wildcard to write the string which replaces the old one.

Is this possible/anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with a

```
sed -i 's/foo\(.*\)foo/hat\1car/g'
```

approach is that it would change `fooxfoo fooyfoo` to `hatxfoo fooycar` as that `.*` is greedy.

You can use `perl` instead with its non-greedy `.*?` operator.

```
perl -i -pe 's/foo(.*?)foo/hat$1car/g'
```

(which also has the advantage of being more portable. That `-i` comes from `perl` and is not available in many `sed` implementations (and when it is, is not interpreted the same by all)).

With GNU `sed`, and provided `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is not in the environment, you could do:

```
sed -i 's/foo/\n/g;s/\n\([^\n]*\)\n/hat\1car/g;s/\n/foo/g'
```

That is, replace `foo` with a character (`\n`, the line delimiter) that cannot occur in the line so we can use `[^\n]*` to achieve the non-greedy equivalent.

If POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment, then `[^\n]` would match any character but `\` and `n` as POSIX requires instead of any character but newline. You can always do:

```
(unset -v POSIXLY_CORRECT; exec sed...)
```

if you want your script to still work in environments where POSIXLY_CORRECT is set.

Answer (score 1):

The replacement string in `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` is not a regular expression.

You will be able to *capture* what is matched by a bit of the pattern and use it in the replacement if you wish:

```
sed -r 's/foo(.*)foo/hat\1car/g' file
```

This will capture anything between two occurrences of `foo` on the same line, and insert that bit between `hat` and `car`.  The `\1` says "insert anything that was captured by the first parentheses".

Note that `.*` is "greedy" so if you have `foobarfoofoobarfoo`, `\1` will be `barfoofoobar`, not `bar`.

Answer (score -1):

With sed, you can use `\(` and `\)` to make a capture group which can be referenced as `\1` in the replacement part of the substitution:

```
 sed 's/foo\(.*\)foo/hat\1car/g'
```